# How to replace label with dates

Tags: vb.net, label, datetimepicker

I am using Visual Basic 2010. My question can best explained by these images[image: Example].

I would like to know how to make the labels appear as dates depending on what the DateTimePicker is set on. For Example:

[image: example]

This is what the code looks now that I have solved my issue.

```
Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateChanged
        Me.Label14.Text = CStr(Me.MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start)
        Me.Label13.Text = CStr(Me.MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.AddDays(6))
        Me.Label12.Text = CStr(Me.MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.AddDays(1))
        Me.Label11.Text = CStr(Me.MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.AddDays(2))
        Me.Label10.Text = CStr(Me.MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.AddDays(3))
        Me.Label9.Text = CStr(Me.MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.AddDays(4))
        Me.Label15.Text = CStr(Me.MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.AddDays(5))
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question.

### To retrieve a date and display it in a label:

1. In the File menu, click New Project.
2. The New Project dialog box appears.
3. Click Windows Forms Application and then click OK.
4. Add a Label control to the form, leaving the default name Label1.
5. Remove the text from the Text property of the Label control.
6. Add a MonthCalendar control to the form, leaving the default name MonthCalendar1.
7. Double-click the MonthCalendar control to enter the default event handler in the Code Editor.
8. In the MonthCalendar1_DateChanged event handler, add the following code to add items to the list:

   `Me.Label1.Text = CStr(Me.MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start)`
9. Return to Designer view and add a DateTimePicker control to the form, leaving the default name DateTimePicker1.
10. Double-click the DateTimePicker control to enter the default event handler in the Code Editor.
11. In the DateTimePicker_ValueChanged event handler, add the following code to add items to the list:

    `Me.Label1.Text = CStr(Me.DateTimePicker1.Value)`
12. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the program.
13. When the form appears, click a date in the MonthCalendar control and verify that the date is displayed in the label.
14. Click the drop-down arrow of the DateTimePicker control and select a date.
15. The date and time are displayed in the label.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Visual Studio installed on this computer, so I can't give you the exact code, so I will try to explain it.

In the code of the event for the DateTimePicker, you have to calculate for each label the difference in days of the week from your date to the date you want to show (Wednesday to Saturday - 3 days (and you have a little error in the images - you have to switch Wednesday with Tuesday), Thursday to Saturday - 2 days, and so on...).

After that, you subtract (or add, if the day is after the chosen date) the referential date with the corresponding value from above, and you get the date needed. Now you only have to show the result in the label.